# Spring-security OAuth2 gives server error on Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, spring-boot, spring-security

I've built a application with spring-boot and deployed it to google app engine where it worked as expected. I later added spring-security and OAuth2 support with the `@EnableOAuth2Sso` annotation. With the following code.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class SpringBootExampleApplication extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/") // Start page
                    .permitAll()
                .anyRequest() // Everything that is not start-page is authenticated
                    .authenticated();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootExampleApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

When testing locally the app works perfectly but when I deploy to app engine and try to access the page I get a server error 500 with the following stack trace.

```
o.s.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils      : Failed to introspect annotations on [class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.ResourceServerTokenServicesConfiguration$RemoteTokenServicesConfiguration$SocialTokenServicesConfiguration]: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not obtain annotation attribute value for public abstract java.lang.Class[] org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnClass.value()

o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.ResourceServerTokenServicesConfiguration$RemoteTokenServicesConfiguration$SocialTokenServicesConfiguration.socialTokenServices
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:64) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:102) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:178) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:140) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:116) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:320) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:228) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:270) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:93) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:525) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:151) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:131) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:86) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169) [spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.plus.annotation.ContainerInitializer.callStartup(ContainerInitializer.java:140) [runtime-impl-third-party.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.ServletContainerInitializersStarter.doStart(ServletContainerInitializersStarter.java:63) [runtime-impl-third-party.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) [runtime-impl-third-party.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:330) [runtime-impl-third-party.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1406) [runtime-impl-third-party.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1368) [runtime-impl-third-party.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:778) [runtime-impl-third-party.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:262) [runtime-impl-third-party.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:522) [runtime-impl-third-party.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) [runtime-impl-third-party.jar:na]
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:244) [runtime-impl.jar:na]
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:182) [runtime-impl.jar:na]
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:97) [runtime-impl.jar:na]
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchServletRequest(JavaRuntime.java:650) [runtime-impl.jar:na]
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchRequest(JavaRuntime.java:612) [runtime-impl.jar:na]
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:582) [runtime-impl.jar:na]
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$NullSandboxRequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:776) [runtime-impl.jar:na]
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:263) [runtime-impl.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_112-google-v7]

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanSearchSpec.collect(OnBeanCondition.java:329) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanSearchSpec.<init>(OnBeanCondition.java:282) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:76) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    ... 37 common frames omitted
```

If I remove the `@EnableOAuth2Sso` annotation the app works. I tried changing form spring-boot 1.5.6 to 1.5.4 but the error still persists.  Why does it work locally but not when deployed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it turns out that is was a bug in spring or app engine https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/10553. A temporary fix is to add `spring-social` as a dependency.